# International SWIFT transfer: sent as OUR, received as SHR (field 71A)

Tags: banking, international-transfer, swift

The company I'm working with sent me a few SWIFT payments, and they all were received with the following fields:

```
:71A:SHA
:71F:USD16,00
:71F:USD0,
```

So the 16$ fee was deducted from the full amount each time. I've asked the company to cover the fee. But it turned out they are sending the payment as `OUR` (and provided me a PDF receipt from their bank that clearly states `OUR`), so the fee should be covered

Client support in my bank said they don't know the full story, but my bank received the payment annotated as `SHR` and can only recommend forcing the payment to use their correspondent bank

Should the 71A field changing it's value during the transfer be possible at all?

Comment: No. I expect the bank is making an extra buck, as they like to do on wire transfers.

Comment: its really normal with wire xfers that banks in the middle plain "rip off".  the "we will pay" can only be seen as a request / hope at best, unfortunately :/